# Extending 3rd party Joomla Components & Modules

Tags: joomla1.5

If I wanted to extend a Joomla module, K2 for example, what is "best practices" for this?

I've come across a situation where someone has modified a 3rd party module by making changes directly to the modules source files. I spent a few years as a Drupal developer, and this is generally considered bad practice because if a critical update comes out for the module, it's difficult to implement because code hacks have to be transferred to the new update - and if you forget, your site is crash. With Drupal, you would write a new custom module and use Drupal API's "hooks" to modify the 3rd party module to do what it needs to do.

Modifying modules and components directly doesn't seem like a good idea to me - If you are a Joomla ninja and you know the Drupal way, weigh in on this, or perhaps point me to a good reference?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that it depends. In some cases, you can simply use the override system to accomplish what you are trying to do. Most every decently coded module or component will allow you to use overrides. You can get quite a lot done this way as far as layout and display code.

In other cases, you can use plugins to alter the output based on a variety of triggers. Joomla has a slew of built in triggers that are used for the plugin system. You can find a complete list of the various Joomla events here - http://docs.joomla.org/Tutorial:Plugins

Lastly, since you mentioned K2, this is a great example of an extension that was built with the intention of being extended. Not only does K2 have it's own triggers for K2 specific plugins, but it also has the ability to extend admin functionality through the use of admin plugins. This really allows you a lot of flexibility in making K2 do what ever you want it to do.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Brent. In Drupal, it is NEVER okay to edit the source of a third party module (or the core). Is this not the case in Joomla? It sounds like you're saying that it's okay? If so, how does Joomla process updates to the original module without breaking the custom code?

Comment: Technically, you should never touch the core code, but not all 3rd party devs put out good code. Joomla updates do not touch extensions, only the core Joomla code so it shouldn't make any difference when you update. If you update the extension, you'd have to account for any hacked code. It is always better to use overrides or plugins to avoid problems with updating.